# Push menu not working properly on default android browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sliding push menu for mobile which is sliding from left to right. It is working fine on all mobile browsers except the default android browser. I have placed menu icon inside my wrapper. When I clicked on menu icon in default browser the menu icon is not sliding towards right. The sliding menu overlaps the icon. But if I change the position from fixed to absolute it works properly.

Please help me to make it compatible with default mobile browser with fixed position.

CSS:

```
#primary-menu-toggle {
    z-index:999 !important;
    top: 84px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="primary-menu" class="menu menu-left">
    navigation items
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <a href="#" id="primary-menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"></a>
  </div>

</div> <!--container ends-->
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of the actual slider?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
      $('menu').on('click', function ()
       {
        $('drop-menu').show();
       });
      $(body).on('click', function ()
      {
        $('drop-menu').hide();
      });
    });
```